# Rok common error handler

Tags: php

I use this code but show error please help me

```
static public function camelize($id) { $arr = array("strtoupper('\2')", "strtoupper('\1')");

return preg_replace_callback(array(
                       '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e', '/\.(.)/e'
                    ),$arr, $id);

}
```

ERROR is

> UNHANDLED ERROR [2] preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,
>   'strtoupper('')::strtoupper('')', to be a valid callback
>   /home/elit8592/public_html/mea/libraries/rokcommon/RokCommon/Service/ContainerImpl.php:465

Comment: did you read the error message? argument two has to be a function. you're passing in a array of strings. doesn't matter if that array contains what **LOOKS** like a function call -it's still just a array, and PHP doesn't "execute" arrays, or strings.

Comment: what i do plz help i wait ur reply

Comment: Marc B i wait ur reply